# How to configure Application Insights in Blazor Server app to include authenticated user in traces?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights, blazor-server-side

When I follow the application insights docs for ASP.NET, the traces produced by Logger.Log() in Blazor components are logged in Application Insights, but the are not associated with logged in user.

It's probably because of SignalR nature.

**How to configure Application Insights in Blazor Server app to include authenticated user in traces?**

### What I tried

**I've added TelemetryInitializer**

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, UserTelemetryInitializer>();

public class UserTelemetryInitializer : TelemetryInitializerBase
{
    public UserTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(HttpContext platformContext, RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.User.Id =
        telemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId =
            platformContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

but any logs coming from Blazor are not associated with the User:

[image: app insights logs]

My asp.net core 6 app deployed to "On premise ISS" have app insights configured as follows:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options => 
    options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"));
```

and a cookie authentication - authenticated user is always required in the blazor hub

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => options.AutomaticAuthentication = false);

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie()

....

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

However, in the app insights portal **I don't see any user id associated with the traces, requests or exception datasets.**

Why is the user_Id missing in the logs?

Comment: There's no trace message in transaction search blade from appinsights in azure portal? There always gather logger information from the project. And if the logger doesn't work in this scenario, did you try to add custom telemetry sir?

Comment: There are traces, request, exceptions, etc., but there is no userId or authenticatedUserId logged

Comment: having same issue here... tried this configuration, but still authenticated user isn't being sent with telemetry data. This is very frustrating